# define another function within an ASYNC function in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, ionic-framework, async-await

How can I define another function within an ASYNC function in Angular? I want to call a function and then execute what is inside the promise. I don't know how to do a callback inside async. it also doesn't let me call the async function within another nested function

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Post your code attempts

Answer (score 0):

Using await you can call another method that would return promise

```
async getAsyncData() {
    this.asyncResult = await this.httpClient.get<Employee>(this.url).toPromise();
    console.log('No issues, I will wait until promise is resolved..');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

To call an ASYNC function in angular is like this:

```
async function getNames(){
console.log('Hello this is an example');
}

async function test(){
const response = await getNames();
console.log(response);
}
```

Before invoking you must write await.